# ROS with public Wifi

Tags: ros, wifi, rosmaster, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I want to use ROS to comunicate Simulink and three drones Crazyflie. I have some problems using ROS with the **public wifi** of the University, when I type `rosinit` the error is:
`Cannot connect to ROS master at http://172.30.152.10:11311. Check the specified address or hostname.`
I tried also to run the command at home with the provate wifi and there it works perfectly, what are the reasons and how can I solve it? I need to use ROS at University.

Thank you for your answers.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293367/ros-with-public-wifi/) by [flavia1394](https://answers.ros.org/users/32544/flavia1394/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-06-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-06**:
Just a guess, but there's probably some rules with your university's firewall that IT implemented that's giving you trouble. You'll probably have to talk to your university's IT department or use your own WLAN (I've encountered the same issue at a university).

**Comment by [flavia1394](https://answers.ros.org/users/32544/flavia1394/) on 2018-06-06**:
Thank you for the fast answer, and do you think that if I use my macbook as a personal hotspot could it work?

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-06-06**:
Not sure, I don't use Macs. You can use a wireless router, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found a solution: sharing the connection of an Android mobile phone connected to the public Wifi to my computer, and it works !!! :D

---

Originally posted by [flavia1394](https://answers.ros.org/users/32544/flavia1394/) with karma: 11 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0